# Mathematica: 'Findroot' not returning expected result

Tags: compiler-errors, formatting, wolfram-mathematica

I am currently doing a little project which involves using a pre-defined function I graphed the function, and I am trying to find an x-value answer using a provided y-coordinate. I'm sure there may be other ways, but I must use this particular function. Below is what I currently have:

```
F[L_] := (ArcTan[(L + 80)/25]/Pi + 0.6)*(0.55 - 
    0.4*Cos[(Pi/100)*(L + 10)])

FindRoot[F[L] == 0.8, {x, 55}]
```

I am sure that my function is correct, as I am able to retrieve a graph, which looks right for the function.

I am unsure if maybe I should try changing my '55' value?

Here is the error that I receive from the program:

```
FindRoot::nlnum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `FindRoot` you have F[L], but then you are trying to start at `x=55` - you have mixed up your variables. Either put both to be `L` or both to be `x` in the `FindRoot`.

```
FindRoot[F[L] == 0.8, {L, 55}]
(* {L -> 58.2501} *)
```

Currently it is looking for a solution starting at `L=55`, there are other solutions for larger values of `L`:

```
FindRoot[F[L] == 0.8, {L, 155}]
(* {L -> 122.963} *)
```

Comment: Man, I can't believe I missed that one! Thanks for reminding me how NOT to directly copy off of an input sheet. All is good now.

Comment: I must say it took me a minute of staring at it, having checked that F evaluated correctly to a number when given a numerical value. There is a Mathematica specific stack exchange site btw, mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := (ArcTan[(x + 80)/25]/Pi + 0.6) (0.55 - 0.4 Cos[(Pi/100) (x + 10)])

Plot[{f[x], 0.8}, {x, -1000, 1000}]
```

[image]

```
NSolve[{f[x] == 0.8, 0 < x < 1000}, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 58.2501}, {x -> 122.963}, {x -> 256.049}, {x -> 324.199}, {x -> 455.505},
>  {x -> 524.599}, {x -> 655.26}, {x -> 724.797}, {x -> 855.12}, {x -> 924.915}}
> ```